# curl to python request

Tags: python-2.7, api, curl, watson

I have a curl query which I want to convert into python request :

```
curl -X POST -u <Username>:<password> --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary @../test_file.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"
```

Please let me know how to make a python code out of this to receive the JSON output file.

Comment: Watson Python SDK has an API call to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Watson Developer Cloud to simplify this.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

The following example below shows how use the speech to text. 
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/speech_to_text_v1.py

```
#Example changed to match line.
#curl -X POST -u <Username>:<password> --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" --data-binary @../test_file.flac "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true"

import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    username='<Username>',
    password='<Password>',
    x_watson_learning_opt_out=False
)

print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.models(), indent=2))

print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.get_model('en-US_BroadbandModel'), indent=2))

with open(join(dirname(__file__), '../test_file.flac'), 'rb') as audio_file:
    print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(
        audio_file, content_type='audio/flac', timestamps=True,
        word_confidence=True),
        indent=2))
```